# Unity Pushing Object Script (Little Big Planet like)

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I want to pull an object with the same force that the player pushes that object's rigidbody. However, I don't know how to make such a force equal to the force of walking into the rigidbody.

Here's my code:

```
 //if can push and holds button for pushing
other.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(player.moveInput.x*player.speed*mass, player.moveInput.y * player.speed * mass, player.moveInput.z * player.speed * mass), ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Right now the above code just makes the box fly with a force that is much greater than I expected.

Comment: Are you asking how to push player from object with the same force he pushed to object? Also you should post whole code and explain better what you are asking.

Comment: I'm asking how to make a pull script for a player to pull objects, so that when he moves the object, stay within certain distance, how can I achieve this?

Comment: What does _"... force equal to the force of walking into the rigidbody"_ mean? What is _"the force of walking"_? Also, what is `player.moveInput`?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think I get it: a player moves into an object and you want to move the object along the player?

The easiest way to do this is by far to disregard the forces, as you want

```
object.velocity = player.velocity
```

(Note here the terminology: *speed* is directionless, but *velocity* is a vector and has 3 components, so the above means `object.velocity.x = player.velocity.x`, `object.velocity.y = player.velocity.y` etc.)

---

You might need to calculate a force for it to work in Unity, so lets derive that. I will use `v` for velocity, and `nv` for the 'next velocity'. A normal time update looks like

```
object.nv = object.v + object.force*object.mass*∆t
```

Now we want `object.nv == player.v`:

```
player.v = object.v + object.force*object.mass*∆t
```

Moving everything over:

```
object.force = (player.v - object.v)/(object.mass*∆t)
```

With this equation the player will not be affected at all, but the body your moving into should be moving 'along' with the player.